# git svn returns "out of date" on push and sync in SmartGit and "unable to determine upstream svn information from working tree history" on dcommit

Tags: git, git-svn

I try to push my changes from my local git repro to my company's SVN-repro.

After pull and merge all changes from svn i try to dcommit my changes.

```
git svn dcommit
```

but i get this error:

```
unable to determine upstream svn information from working tree history
```

or

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 852.
```

.. so i try SmartGit but i get another error

```
Push: svn: E160024: File or directory 'trunk' is out of date; try updating svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating svn: E175002: CHECKOUT of '/svn/entwicklung/!svn/ver/21045/trunk': 409 Conflict (http://le-svn)
$ git.exe update-index --refresh
$ git.exe diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
$ git.exe diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD --
$ git.exe update-index --refresh
$ git.exe diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
$ git.exe diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD --
$ git.exe checkout -q 09fc6832ef3111c2c69d29ba3329b20a365c38b3
$ git.exe merge -q --squash 09fc6832ef3111c2c69d29ba3329b20a365c38b3 8b230b96baecb4a2bfbc48f7ba68d42ef2bbba20 0ff6eca016d2b00ab3ab58fffd59a2379c839d6a
Trying simple merge with 8b230b96baecb4a2bfbc48f7ba68d42ef2bbba20
Trying simple merge with 0ff6eca016d2b00ab3ab58fffd59a2379c839d6a
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
$ git.exe commit -q --message Message --allow-empty
$ git.exe checkout -q 6820736762c3fac3c942db0f8e54f150e062e49c
$ git.exe merge -q --squash 6820736762c3fac3c942db0f8e54f150e062e49c cf4da94860388a444028bdece93e421d8cf30102 231bad85bd61cbce1a1a381b9275ed3309f37779
Trying simple merge with cf4da94860388a444028bdece93e421d8cf30102
Trying simple merge with 231bad85bd61cbce1a1a381b9275ed3309f37779
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ git.exe commit -q --message Message --allow-empty
$ git.exe checkout -q --force refs/heads/trunk
$ git.exe reset --hard refs/heads/trunk --
HEAD is now at 3c1dc41 Merge branch 'svn/trunk'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you merging a local branch into another local branch .

Comment: I merge a git branch ("A") to branch ("trunk")

Comment: i have NO branch called "master"

Comment: no i try to push my changes to svn

Comment: I think you again need to pull remote trunk branch to your local trunk branch before pushing data as your local trunk branch is not upto date.

Comment: svn/trunk and git/trunk are sync except for the changes

Comment: Newest SVN Revision is 21049 in git and svn

Comment: have you tried git svn rebase

Comment: yes. i have do this befor but i do it agane .. its runnig and takes a half hour ... i will post the result

Comment: the result of git svn rebase: "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history" but "Pull" (from SVN) in SmartGit works and takes only 3-4 minutes

Comment: Have you committed before you pull the changes. One more option is you have to reset your last commit and then pull and then commit your code again

Comment: All changes are commited to git ... i will try it

Comment: doesn't work :( i have reset the trunk branch to the last commit bevor merging. then rebase the last changes from svn, then merge the branch into trunk, commit and at last try to DCommit.

Comment: This may be a related question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547760/smartgit-file-or-directory-out-of-date-error-message-when-it-is-not/25548180#25548180